# Can't add new app, can't join Facebook community

Tags: facebook

From a previous FB SO question, I worked out that the Create New App button is probably missing because I created the fan page without a proper FB account and I think they want something more concrete to verify me or something. So I created a proper FB account, as me, and now I'm stuck.

I can't join the developer community. The first time I clicked to join, it said "Cancel Request" for a few hours before reverting to Join, so I clicked it again and its been pending ever since - there's no email confirmation, it's all a bit mysterious.

I need to join because I don't think this (SO) is the right place to ask questions about the problems I'm having just setting up a new app, or linking my new account to the fan page.

I'm stuck - my company is blocked to add new features.

Comment: You can't create apps when logged in as a page or as a business account; only a real account which has a credit card or SMS verification on file can do so, and that group is auto-moderated so only users with active applications can be added (the spam count was too high otherwise)

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/apps is where you create a new app - but again, you must be logged in as a regular, verified user

Comment: Thank you - looks like the police are coming to close this question, so before I run for it, do you know how I can make my proper FB account the 'owner' of my page?

Comment: i think you just go into the page settings and add another admin there

Comment: Thanks again Igy (right now even visiting the dev group link redirects me to my page, so I guess they blacklisted me - I even phoned FB in the states and left a message!!).

Comment: Okay something must have happened. I logged in as my real account and went straight to an Authorize page for "Developer" and Create New App appeared. Hallelujah! Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to supply an official answer. I needed to create a proper Facebook account as me, with friends, and then set this account as an administrator of the Facebook page. Then wait for their servers to propagate changes.

Bottom line: if you created your page using a page account (i.e. an account representing your brand and not a person), you can't make apps, and Facebook doesn't give error messages, it just hides options or redirects you round in circles.

Answer (score 2):

You do need to register, then log in to FB, and accept their permissions to become a developer.  I created a very nice step by step guide that takes you through everything, including registering with FB, setting up a Java WebService, Persistence, and registering for FREE web hosting, resulting in a completed demo App with some sample FB calls.  Goes from absolute 0 to fully functioning FB app with this 3 part blog series (part 1 starts here):

http://ocpsoft.org/opensource/creating-a-facebook-app-setup-and-tool-installation/

Comment: +1 for your effort and time on the blog, although I seem to be on track now.